# Are Jinns Another Name For An Angel

Tags: jinn, malaikah, names

Are Jinns another name for an angel, in Arabic, also are Jinns servants to Allah like angels are servants to Allah

Comment: Jinns, Angels, Humans are all different concepts. There are servants to Allah among the Jinns as well as along the Humans.

Comment: Especially some statements in the tafsir of Imam at-Tabari may create a confusion for Iblis being an Angel or a Jinn, but else the Quran is crystal clear when defining Angels, Jinn and Humans.

Answer (score 2):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

No, **angels are different made from NOOR(light), jins are different made from fire. Man was made in the end, with clay**...
**Angels don't have will power**, they only do what they are ordered to do. **But jins and men have will power** and can do whatever they want to. That's why men and jinns will answer for their deeds on judgement day. Not angels.
For a little detailed answer [read here.](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=16265)
Lastly **everyone is servant of Allah**, that's why the servants which have will power in this world and they don't follow the orders of their lord will get punishment. Every thing created by Allah is servant of Allah, willingly or un-willingly.

### Allah Knows best